# SPItemEventReceiver.ItemUpdated : Delete same SPListItem as in properties.ListItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

So, i've got this code:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);

    SPListItem newItem = AMethodWhichGetsANewListItem();   
    properties.ListItem.ParentList.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId).Delete();

    properties.Cancel = true;
    properties.InvalidateListItem();
    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
    properties.RedirectUrl = newItem.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + "=" + newItem.ID;
}
```

This Event now have a ListItem in it's property which is not available.
After this, I cannot cancel or redirect.

The error log shows:

```
`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 iIndex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.EnsureItemIsValid()`
```

Adding `properties.InvalidateListItem()` doesn't do anything.
A try { } catch in the ItemUpdated block won't catch an Exception.

What can I do?

Comment: I don't think it will solve the problem, but calling InvalidateListItem() may make things worse because technically you're asking SharePoint to try to retrieve the item again... the item you've just deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing

```
    SPWeb web = properties.Web;
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the code to ItemUpdating. In this override, everything works perfect.